# check at least a record exists

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

two tables:

```
== customers ==
cust_id

== attachments ==
att_id
cust_id
```

1 customer -> MANY attachments

i would retrieve all the custmers and, adding the boolean virtual field "has_attach" to select, know if a customer have got attachments.

without GROUP BY, if this is possibile :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many `many` really means, the `COUNT(*)` option can impose an un-necessary burden.

In which case, the following *can sometimes* yield benefits.

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM attachments
                     WHERE cust_id = customers.cust_id)
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0 END  AS has_attach
FROM
  customers
```

This is because `EXISTS` doesn't actually read all the records.  It just checks that *any* record exists.

In fact, when using indexes this doesn't even read any records from the table.  It just checks that the index points to any matching records and stops there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    customers .cust_id,
    IFNULL(count , 0) as Total
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT att_id , count(*) as count
        FROM attachments group by cust_id
    ) AS att on att.cust_id = customers.cust_id
```

This is something in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update customers set field='has attach' 
where cust_id in (select c.cust_id cusotmer c
inner join attachment a on c.cust_id=a.cust_id 
having count(a.id)>1
```

Comment: thanks SRIRAM but your sql retrieve only custmenrs with at least one attachment.

Comment: @Roberto to which column the boolean "has_attach" to be added.for that you should add one column in the customers table